# Node.js fs.writeFile save to json keeps looping

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write a json file with some data but I noticed that if I use .json to prograp keep looping endlessy.

If I use .txt instead it works as expected, create the file and save the data. Once.

Why is this?

```js
let users = [
  {
    "firstname": "value",
    "lastname": "value",
  }
]

const json = JSON.stringify(users, null, 2)
const path = 'users.json' // Loops endlessly
const path = 'users.txt' // Works fine
const path = 'users' // Even this works fine, but not what I need

fs.writeFile(path, json, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('File saved successfully')
})
```

Edit

The problem is caused by nodemon somehow. After I added the following script

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --ignore *.json index.js"
},
```

What happened next was that after saving running `npm start` the .json I needed to create wasn't even created.
So that solution didn't work.

Comment: keeps looping endlessy without throwing error?

Comment: correct, it does save the file, but it keeps saving over and over